# Search in listview using edittext

Tags: java, android, listview

I need to search item in listview.I have easy array of String and Array Adapter,put code wich I find at some different questions and its work!But I have one problem,this search is very slow and lags for one letter.I have word "arbuz"(one for many others) and I print a-nothing,some another letter-and words search for "a",another-and no words like this.I hope you unterstand me.How I can improve this search?
My code:

```
public class FragmentWithList extends ListFragment {
    ListView mainList;
    EditText inputSearch;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_with_list, null);
        mainList = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        inputSearch = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        return v;


    }
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String values[] = new String[]{"arbuz","abrikos","banan","cup","charlie","derevo","grusha","ogurets","sliva","jabloko","volk","dom","igra","pharaon","muscle"};
        Comparator<String> ALPHABETICAL_ORDER1 = new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String object1, String object2) {
                int res = String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(object1.toString(), object2.toString());
                return res;
            }
        };

        Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(values), ALPHABETICAL_ORDER1);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
        mainList.setAdapter(adapter);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can Use AutoComplete Textview instead of using an EditText. AutoComplete Textview handles ,textwatcher, editoractionlistener itself. So its easy to use.. try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code in the `afterTextChanged()` method

```
adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
```